# One-off animations in react-spring

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, react-spring

I have the following in a react component:

```
  const revealSpringRef = useSpringRef();
  const revealSpring = useSpring({
    ref: revealSpringRef,
    // transform: isSubtitleHovered ? 'translate(0%, -115%)' : 'translate(0%, 0%)',
    from: isSubtitleHovered
      ? { transform: 'translate(0%, 0%)' }
      : { transform: 'translate(0%, -115%)' },
    to: isSubtitleHovered
      ? { transform: 'translate(0%, -115%)' }
      : { transform: 'translate(0%, 0%)' },
    config: { mass: 1, friction: 15, tension: 170 },
  });

  const teaseSpringRef = useSpringRef();
  const teaseSpring = useSpring({
    ref: teaseSpringRef,
    from: { backgroundColor: 'red' },
    to: { backgroundColor: 'green' },
    // from: { transform: 'translate(0%, -115%)' },
    // to: { transform: 'translate(0%, 0%)' },
    config: { mass: 1, friction: 15, tension: 170 },
  });

  useChain([teaseSpringRef, revealSpringRef]);
```

What I can't figure out is how to apply both of these springs to a *single element*.  I see lots of stuff about applying the second spring to a child element, but that's not what I want.

Basically I want the page to load, one little animation to run, then, on hover, the other one runs.  Is this possible in `react-spring`?